# mysql match on a string subset

Tags: mysql, string, substr

With table:

```
idx | int | ident
1   | 10  | Foo 001_10
2   | 10  | Farfoo 002_11
3   | 11  | Sofoo 001_11
4   | 10  | Lafoo 001_10
5   | 10  | MoreFoo 001_11
```

How can I select all rows where the last 2 characters in the string 'ident' do not match the integer in the 'int' coloumn? Which for the table above would be:

```
2   | 10  | Farfoo 002_11
5   | 10  | MoreFoo 001_11
```

Comment: you cannot use `int` as column name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use [**RIGHT**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_right) string function using
   `right(ident,2)` you will get the last two digits from string then compare it will int column 
   if both are unequal then retrieve the not matching contents.

```
select * from tablename
where RIGHT(ident,2) != int;
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use the [SUBSTRING](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring) function, you will have something like that

`SELECT * FROM table WHERE SUBSTRING(ident, -2) != int`

But I'm not sure if it the best way to reach your goal. Substring can be a very expensive method for MySQL, maybe someone else knows faster and better method.

Here a better way, that allows you to get everything after the last `_`, because I'm not sure that you gonna always have two digit after `_`. For that case, I'm using [SUBSTRING_INDEX](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index).

`SELECT * FROM table WHERE SUBSTRING_INDEX(ident, '_',  -1) != int`

Comment: +1.  Beat me to it.  I don't think there is a better way to do it in SQL, though you are right about it being expensive as it needs to do a full table scan, plus a `SUBSTRING` operation on each row.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT idx, `int`, `ident` FROM table WHERE SUBSTRING(`ident`, -2, 2) != `int`;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from whatever where not ident like concat('%', cast `int` as varchar);
```